# How to get ref from a React 16 portal?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, portal

Is there a way to get `ref` from a React 16 portal. I tried the following approach but it doesn't seem to work:

```
const Tooltip = props => (
  ReactDOM.createPortal(
    <div>{props.children}</div>,
    // A DOM element
    document.body
  )
);

class Info extends React.Component {
   render() {
      return (
        <Tooltip 
          ref={ el => this.tooltip = el }
        >
          My content
        </Tooltip>
      ); 
   }

   componentDidMount() {
      console.log(this.tooltip); // undefined
   }
}
```

I need the `ref` in order to dynamically calculate the element final position!

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/QqmBpB

Comment: What is weird is that you use this to render into body. I mean, for a portal you need a valid dom element in the first place?

Comment: isn't `document.body` a valid dom element?

Comment: Yes, sure. I get it’s just an example. But it seems the wrong way round what you’re trying. After all, The root dom of the portal is the one you’re rendering into. I suspect that for normal components actually rendering jsx objects ref should still work. Can you try that?

Comment: I think I got the problem. `ReactDOM.createPortal` returns returns a ReactPortal instance, which is a valid ReactNode but not a valid DOM element

Answer (score 8):

`ReactDOM.createPortal` returns a [ReactPortal](https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/589c0a25dfa18c2090549cc6f5b626d69ea53c2a/src/renderers/shared/fiber/isomorphic/ReactTypes.js#L43-L50) instance, which is a valid [ReactNode](https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/master/src/renderers/shared/fiber/isomorphic/ReactTypes.js#L17) but not a valid DOM element. At the same time `createPortal` will honour the component context. So I moved the function call to be inside the render method and it solved the issue.

```
class Info extends React.Component {
  render() {
    // I moved the portal creation to be here
    return ReactDOM.createPortal(
       // A valid DOM node!!
       <div ref={ el => this.tooltip = el }>{props.children}</div>,
       // A DOM element
       document.body
    ); 
  }

  componentDidMount() {
     console.log(this.tooltip); // HTMLDivElement
  }
}
```

Comment: If you wanted to keep `Info` and `App` separate, you could get access to the `Info` portal's DOM node from `App` with `this.tooltip.tooltip`

Answer (score 2):

If you want to do it with hooks, you can also do

```
import { createPortal } from 'react-dom'
import React, { useRef } from 'react'

const Portal = ({ children }) => {
  const portal = useRef(document.createElement('div'))
  return createPortal(children, portal.current)
}
```

Also, in your exact example, you would need to use `forwardRef` since you can't pass `refs` to children without it.

```
const Tooltip = forwardRef((props, ref) => (
  createPortal(
    <div ref={ref}>{props.children}</div>,
    // A DOM element
    document.body
  )
));

const Info = () => {
  const ref = useRef()
  return (
    <Tooltip ref={ref}>
      My content
    </Tooltip>
  )
}
```

This last bit is not tested, but I'm pretty sure it'll work.

Comment: Thanks for the version on the Hooks with forwardRef + createPortal. Exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `this.tooltip.props.children` in App component and use the following code for the Tooltip component:

```
const appRoot = document.getElementById('app-root');
const tooltipRoot = document.getElementById('tooltip-root');

class Tooltip extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    // Create a div that we'll render the Tooltip into
    this.el = document.createElement('div');
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    // Append the element into the DOM on mount.
    tooltipRoot.appendChild(this.el);
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    // Remove the element from the DOM when we unmount
    tooltipRoot.removeChild(this.el);
  }

  render() {
    // Use a portal to render the children into the element
    return ReactDOM.createPortal(
      // Any valid React child: JSX, strings, arrays, etc.
      this.props.children,
      // A DOM element
      this.el,
    );
  }
}

class App extends React.Component {
      componentDidMount() {
        console.log(this.tooltip.props.children);
      }
      render() {
        return (
          <div>
            <Tooltip ref={ el => this.tooltip = el }>
              My content
            </Tooltip>
          </div>
        );
      }
    }

ReactDOM.render(<App />, appRoot);
```

Working demo https://codepen.io/jorgemcdev/pen/aLYRVQ, based on Dan Abramov code sample https://codepen.io/gaearon/pen/jGBWpE